# Avoiding looping through pandas dataframe for feature generation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working on some code that generates features from a dataframe and adds these features as columns to the dataframe.

The trouble is I'm working with a time series so that for any given tuple, I need (let's say) 5 of the previous tuples to generate the corresponding feature for that tuple.

```
lookback_period = 5
df['feature1'] = np.zeros(len(df)) # preallocate

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index < lookback_period:
        continue
    slice = df[index - lookback_period:index] 
    some_int = SomeFxn(slice)
    row['feature1'] = some_int
```

Is there a way to execute this code without explicitly looping through every row and then slicing?

One way is to create several lagged columns using `df['column_name'].shift()` such that all the necessary information is contained in each row, but this quickly gets intractable for my computer's memory since the dataset is large (millions of rows).

Comment: have you looked at [`.loc()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)? you can try `my_df.loc['CONDITION_HERE' , 'COLUMN_TO_CHANGE] = 'VALUE_HERE'`

Comment: I'm familiar with it but how might I be able to use it to execute an operation on the last lookback_period tuples?

Comment: you may have to use `.iloc` in combination with `.loc`. I'm slightly confused on expected output. maybe you can add a sample dataframe and a sample desired outcome?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so will just post it here.

Can't you use apply for your dataframe e.g.

df['feature1'] = df.apply(someRowFunction, axis=1)

where someRowFunction will accept the full row and you can perform whatever row based slice and logic you want to do.

--- updated ---

As we do not have much information about the dataframe and the required/expected output, I just based the answer on the information from the comments

Let's define a function that will take a DataFrame slice (based on current row index and lookback) and the row and will return sum of the first column of the slice and value of the current row.

```
def someRowFunction (slice, row):
    if slice.shape[0] == 0:
        return 0
    return slice[slice.columns[0]].sum() + row.b

d={'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],'b':[0,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
lookback = 5
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda current_row: someRowFunction(df[current_row.name -lookback:current_row.name],current_row),axis=1)
```

we can get row index from apply using its name attribute and as such we can retrieve the required slice. Above will result to the following

```
print(df)
   a  b   c
0  1  0   0
1  2  9   0
2  3  8   0
3  4  7   0
4  5  6   0
5  6  5  20
6  7  4  24
7  8  3  28
8  9  2  32
9  0  1  36
```

Comment: But the input to someRowFunction is both the current row and lookback_period=5 rows before it. Is there a way to use df.apply() on rolling slices of a dataframe?

Comment: You interpreted the question correctly, the result above is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. The only thing I'm unsure about now is whether df.apply() with a lambda function is any faster than using df.iterrows()